# Service in ionic 3

Tags: sockets, ionic-framework, service, ionic3

In the past I made an Android App, and I created a Service that works when the app has been destroyed (not in background).

Now, I'm doing the same app in ionic and I need the same, a Service which works when the app is destroyed.

In this service I have to receive information and, depending on what I get, make a local notification.

I've found something that could be useful: [BackgroundMode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/), but when the app is destroyed, the plugin stops working.

I´m looking for a Service in Ionic 3, which could achieve the idea exposed previously, because I want an open socket that could recieve information even when the app is not running.

I don't want Push notifications, I want to keep a socket opened in a service.

Is it possible?

Comment: I know you said you didn't want to use them but in my experience the best way to achieve something close to what you are after here is using push notifications. Is there a way your use case could be modified to make use of them instead?

Comment: I don't want use push notifications because i don't want change the server but... i don't find other solution... i can't understand why is not possible make a service in ionic... in the end it will be best to build my own plugin...

Comment: It should be possible using the plugin you referenced but it looks like there is an issue with Android 8 - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/380

Comment: I can´t use that plugin because it don´t work when I destroy the App